# Calling an custom field from theme option at the frontend

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, functions, theme-options

I am having trouble calling a field and displaying its content at the frontend from a custom theme option page. This is the code I am using to display my custom theme option at the backend

```
  add_action( 'admin_init', 'theme_options_init' );
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'theme_options_add_page' );

 /** Init plugin options to white list our options **/
  function theme_options_init(){
        register_setting( 'options', 'website_options', 'theme_options_validate' );
  }
 /** Load up the menu page **/
  function theme_options_add_page() {
        add_theme_page( __( 'Blurb Options', 'websiteBlurbs' ), __( 'Blurb Options',      'websiteBlurbs' ), 'edit_theme_options', 'theme_options', 'theme_options_do_page' );
 }

 /** Create the options page **/
  function theme_options_do_page() {
            if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) )
            $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] = false;
 ?>
  <div class="wrap">
  <?php screen_icon(); echo "<h2>" . get_current_theme() . __( ' Page Settings', 'websiteBlurbs' ) . "</h2>"; ?>
  <?php if ( false !== $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) : ?>
  <div class="updated fade"><p><strong><?php _e( 'Options saved', 'websiteBlurbs' ); ?></strong></p></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields( 'options' ); ?>
        <?php $options = get_option( 'website_options' ); ?>
        <table class="form-table">
            <td><h2>About Page</h2></td>
            <?php /* ABOUT */ ?>
            <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Title Blurb', 'aboutBlurb' ); ?></th>
        <td>
                    <input id="website_options[about]" class="regular-text" type="text" name="website_options[about]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options['about'] ); ?>" style="width:50%; padding:1em;" />
                    <label class="description" for="website_options[about]"></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td><h2>Our Team</h2></td>
            <?php /* PROPERTY */ ?>
            <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Title Blurb', 'teamBlurb' ); ?></th>
                <td>
                    <input id="website_options[team]" class="regular-text" type="text" name="website_options[team]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options['team'] ); ?>" style="width:50%; padding:1em;" />
                    <label class="description" for="website_options[team]"></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td><h2>Property Page</h2></td>
            <?php /* PROPERTY */ ?>
            <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Title Blurb', 'propertyBlurb' ); ?></th>
                <td>
                    <input id="website_options[property]" class="regular-text" type="text" name="website_options[property]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options['property'] ); ?>" style="width:50%; padding:1em;" />
                    <label class="description" for="website_options[property]"></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Options', 'websiteBlurbs' ); ?>" />
        </p>
  </form>
  </div>
  <?php
 }

 /** Sanitize and validate input. Accepts an array, return a sanitized array. **/
  function theme_options_validate( $input ) {
 // Say our text option must be safe text with no HTML tags
        $input['about'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['about'] );
        $input['property'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['property'] );
        $input['team'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['team'] );
        return $input;
 }
```

I know how to call a field from a custom post type by using echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'customfieldname', true); but when I try using this to call field aboutBlurb i am unable to generate the content from the field to display at the frontend. I am not receiving any errors or a reasons why I can not display it.

What am I missing to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you've decided to save your options but if I were to guess based on the code above, you're saving your 'aboutBlurb' as an index in the `website_options` array which I also assume you're saving in the actual [WordPress Options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) - `website_options[about]`.

To get that data maybe try this:

```
$website_options = get_option('website_options');
echo $website_options['about'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, may help you. I fetch the a page 's thread then fetch associated custom field by putting its name.

```
     $homeInsurance= new WP_Query( 'post_type=page&page_id=7' );    
        while ($homeInsurance->have_posts()) : $homeInsurance->the_post();

        $thisPageID         = get_the_id(); 
        $home_insurance_urdu_translation_image_path = get_post_meta($thisPageID, 'home_insurance_urdu_translation_image_path', true);


        endwhile;
```